# С консоли не записывается кириллица в файл

Tags: c#

Я недавно начал изучать c#. И столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Я создаю простое консольное приложение и хочу, записать в файл то что я ввожу в консоль.

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.Default))
{
   sw.WriteLine(str);
   sw.Close();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Я указывал разную кодировку (UTF-8, Unicode), но файл все равно выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может дело в настройке самой командной строки?

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(file, str);` без явного указания кодировки запишет файл в UTF-8. А `Encoding.Default` - это UTF-16. Еще многое зависит от того, чем вы этот файл смотрите. Попробуйте открыть его, скажем, с помощью Notepad++ или даже обратно прочитать и вывести в консоль `Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(file));`.

Comment: Чтобы правильно указать стримрайтеру кодировку UTF-8, надо сделать вот так `new StreamWriter(file, new UTF8Encoding(false))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема не в коде - проблема в поддержке виндовсом кодировки в консоли.

Попробуй Start > Control panel > Region
на вкладке Administrative, в секции Language for non-Unicode programs, нажми на кнопку и смени локаль по умолчанию на Russian (Russia)
после перезагрузки проблема должна изчезнуть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данная настройка уже была, но подредактировал формат, на  "Использовать язык интерфейса Windows(рекомендуется)" и снял галку с "Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире". Перезагрузил и все заработало!) Спасибо за подсказку!!